# Editing the values of a column in Oracle reports

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

I have a oracle report which is to display a set of values and it can be generated both as pdf and csv formats.
I had to make sure that these values always shows upto 3 decimals. That is:

```
0.1  --> 0.100
0.01 --> 0.010
0    --> 0.000
```

Excel doesnt consider the trainling zeros and so I used the following code for making excel display all the 3 decimals:

```
select '="'||to_char(value,'90.999')||'"' from table1; 
--The column is declared as NUMBER(10,3) in the table
```

Now the number shows up in the excel as desired, but in pdf format it shows like : =" 0.000"

Can anyone please tell me how to make it consistent in both pdf and csv formats?

Comment: First, just to be clear, this is a report you're building inside the Oracle Reports product?  Not a SQL statement that happens to be used to generate a report from an Oracle database?  What version of Oracle Reports are you using?  What are the distribution settings on the report?

Comment: yes! I am using sql queries to get the data from DB and using the paper layout to generate the reports. And am using oracle reports builder 10.1.2

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set the format mask of the field in your Oracle report to `'0.000'` and then once you generate your Excel report manually set the column format to show the decimals? Or even perhpas use a custom piece of VBA to do it automatically for you.

Comment: yes, but i wanted a more general solution than to do change the column formating in excel everytime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could evaluate the format parameter of the report at runtime and use a DECODE statement or CASE statement to determine which output format / value for the column.

I think this would achieve what you are aiming for ie. a single structured report using the same query for either csv or pdf output.

Comment: Thanks. My only concern is the performance issue. If there are around 5000 values, then the decode would have to go on so many times. Doesnt that make things slow??

Comment: I doubt it would have a significant impact on a table with 5000 rows. That is (relatively) a very small number of rows. The best thing to do would be to check by running the query through an explain plan and comparing before and after.

Answer (score -2):

In my project i tried below way ,

```
          IF :DESFORMAT='SPREADSHEET' THEN
                   :CP_2:= '="'||:cmdt_grp_cd||'"';
           ELSE
                   :CP_2:=:cmdt_grp_cd;
           END IF;
```